# How to Construct a String from Data Dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dictionary like this: `Data = [{'type': 'string'}, {'primary_key': True}]`. With that, I tried to construct a string of format like here `"db.Column(type=string, primary_key=True)"` but it was not success.

Here is what I tried:

```
ColumnDef = 'db.Column({kwarg})'
Data = [{'type': 'string'}, {'primary_key': True}]

kw_field = {}

for item in Data:
    kw_field.update(item)

ColumnDef = ColumnDef.format(kwarg=kw_field)

print (ColumnDef)

# db.Column({'type': 'string', 'primary_key': True})
```

How can I achieve the above string result? Thanks.

Comment: Which output do you want? `"db.Column({'type': 'string', 'primary_key': True})"` or `"db.Column(type=string, primary_key=True)"`.

Comment: @Ava, I want a later one `"db.Column(type=string, primary_key=True)"`, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```py
Data = [
    {'type': 'string'},
    {'primary_key': True}
]

ColumnDef = f"""db.Column({', '.join(
    [
        f"{k}={v}" for d in Data
        for k, v in d.items()
    ]
)})"""

print(ColumnDef)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it is as I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ColumnDef.format(kwarg=', '.join([f"{key}={val}" for data in Data for key, val in data.items()]))
```

results in: `'db.Column({type=string, primary_key=True})'`
If you have:

```
ColumnDef = 'db.Column({kwarg})'
Data = [{'type': 'string'}, {'primary_key': True}]
```